# How to make a phone call in react native and place it in the background

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a phone call with react-native and have it automatically be in the background (stay in my app), is it possible to achieve this? also When pressing the button to make the call a prompt pops up saying "call (###)###-####" is there a way around the prompt to make a direct call? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run: **npm i react-native-phone-call**

it's ultimately just a wrapper for:

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`)

<Text onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('tel:${phoneNumber}`);} }>${phoneNumber}`</Text>
```

Check this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-call

Comment: thank you, but this method leaves the app. Do you know a way to return back to the app or have it make the call in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I think react-native-callkeep might be more what you're looking for, as it allows you to make calls without leaving your app.

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep

Comment: This seems like something that would work, thank you so much. I’ll check it out and let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: I installed callkeep but when importing it I get an error stating " `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null arguments.' Do you know if I can use this in expo (no ios / android folder)

Comment: Going by their issue tracker, unfortunately Expo doesn't support this library. I don't have an Expo alternative for you right now, but you could consider ejecting your app.